# Datepicker not highlighting specified dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am trying to highlight an array of dates in a date picker, however i cannot seem to get it working. I know my jQuery is loading in the browser. Any and all help appreciated.

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('booking_date', 'booking_time', 'number_attending')
        widgets = {
            'booking_date': DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date', 'id': 'datepicker'})
        }
```

script.js

```
   var dates = ['14-10-2023', '15-10-2023', '16-10-2023'];

    $('#datepicker').datepicker
        ({
            beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yyyy', date);
                if ($.inArray(string, dates) == -1) {
                    return [true, 'highlighted-date'];
                } else {
                    return [true, ''];
                }
            },
        });
```

css

```
.highlighted-date {
    color: red;
}
```

script tags

```
 <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
      integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"
      integrity="sha256-6XMVI0zB8cRzfZjqKcD01PBsAy3FlDASrlC8SxCpInY="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are formatting the date within the beforeShowDay callback function, the date is being formatted into an invalid format ie. "14-10-20232023", if you remove the last two "y"s from the formatDate() function the date will be formatted as you intend.

In your code you are "highlighting" all dates, except those in the dates array, in my example it is the opposite, you would just need to change the if statement depending on your needs.

Also looking at the datepicker, it is rendered in HTML as a table, thus when the "highlighted-date" class is added it will be added to the (td) element, which contains an (a) element. So you will also need to update your CSS and potentially include the "!important" tag if you are using something like bootstrap, or if other CSS is overriding the "highlighted-date" class styles.

```js
var dates = ['14-10-2023', '15-10-2023', '16-10-2023'];

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd-mm-yy', date);
        if ($.inArray(string, dates) != -1) {
            return [true, 'highlighted-date'];
        } else {
            return [true, ''];
        }
    },
});
```

```css
.highlighted-date a{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


Date Picker on input field: <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="date"/>
```